# How to Render Images in Javascript with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Rails 3.1 now requires you to use `image_tag` when rendering an image using the asset pipeline.

I have built endless scroll into my application and have put the code into a js.coffee file. I wish to render a spinning loading gif whilst more products are loaded. I cannot use `image_tag` here as this file does not support rails code, but I have written it in here so you understand what I am trying to do.

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 1200
        $('.pagination').html("<%= image_tag("loading.gif") %> Loading more...")
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```

Previously, I would have just written it in pure HTML, using `<img src=...` But this will no longer work with the asset pipeline. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using plain HTML should work just fine.

Try using: `<img src="/assets/loading.gif" />` if your `loading.gif` is inside `assets/images`.

**UPDATED 21/06/2012**

As per the [Ruby on Rails Guide, Section 2.2.3](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets), changing the file extension of your .js file to `filename.js.erb` or `filename.js.coffee.erb` will allow you to use embedded ruby inside your javascript.

You can then use the `asset_path` helper to access the path where your assets are stored.

Comment: Will this not only work in production if I include the fingerprint part? It would have to be something like <img src="/assets/loading-3ca5380af3c933ae32.gif" />

Comment: Hmm, good point. I hadn't thought of that, as I was only toying around with something on my dev environment. I'll take a look into it here shortly.

Comment: I mean I could put the image_tag in a div in the view with display none and then put $('.paginationLoader').show() in the js code. But this just seems unnecessary, and a bit of a work around, there must surely be a better way. Would be interested if you were able to come up with anything, thanks!

Comment: According to the documentation, you should be able to access the `asset_path` helper from your coffeescript file. [Look here at section 2.2.3](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets).

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work initially. I'll try some tweaking when I'm home later, it does look promising. Should at least help know what terms to search for a little better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Zajn, I managed to figure out the answer from the guide you linked to. In the end, i changed the file to .js.coffee.erb and used the following code... $('.pagination').html("<img src='<%= asset_path('loading.gif') %>' /> Loading More...")

Comment: Hey, I'm glad that worked out for you! I'll update my answer to reflect what helped you solve the problem.